# Unanimous approval

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have a custom object on which I am having a user lookup field "App1". On the other hand, I am having an approval process where I have mapped "App1" field as an approver and I have also selected unanimous option checkbox.

Now when I submit a record for approval it goes to "App1" user. This user doesn't want to approve it and reassigns it to a queue. Now every queue member gets notified. All is working fine so far. But if any member from the queue approves the record then it gets approved despite we have selected unanimous checkbox.

Here I want that record should get approved only when all the members of the queue approve the record.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unanimous Checkbox refers to each person or group within the approval process.  Although the queue is made of many queue members, the queue counts as one approver, so whoever from the queue approves the record, is approving it on behalf of the entire queue.  So as the way the approval process is set up, this is unanimous approval.  In order to accomplish what you are trying to do each individual person would have to be named in the approval process.  Then unanimous approval would require each individual person to approve before the pparoval goes through.

This is similar to using a queue as a record owner, although there can be multiple members of the queue, the queue still only counts as one entity, not a group made up by its members.

I hope that makes sense and helps.

Comment: I would disagree. According to salesforce, unanimous requires approval from all of the approvers at the same level. According to you, there is no difference between normal and unanimous approval process. Please correct me I am wrong.

Comment: What you are saying is correct.  What I am saying is that the queue only counts as 1 approver.  If you want each person in the queue to count as a separate approver, you need to add each person as an approver.  Salesforce looks at the queue as one approver, not a group of seperate approvers.  So one person in the queue approving the record, approves the record on behalf of the entire queue.

Comment: In that case, what is the use of unanimous checkbox? or what does it mean by unanimous approval at every level?

Comment: Unanimous check box means approval needs to be given by every "approver" listed whether than be User, RelatedUser or Queue.  It's just that the first assigned in the queue to response speaks for the whole queue.   Consider if you've got approvers listed as Queue1 and Queue2.  Unanimous approval means approval from one person in each queue.